# Regex to find substring from string using groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to get **http://IP:PORT/idoc/idoc/dashboard/10057** from below string using regex in groovy.

```
SO_Status:0</br>SO_Log:Idoc healthcheck has been performed on system.</br>SO_output:Idoc healthcheck has been performed on system.</br>SO_url:http://IP:PORT/idoc/idoc/dashboard/10057
```

Want to know regex pattern. Thanks in advance

Comment: hope this king of properties file i.e. some_key:someValue and maybe have own parser?

Comment: Can't you just grep for `http://` and anchor off the end of the string?

Comment: Actually, I want to do this using GroovyScriptTemplate hence needed exact regex pattern to get url